# A function that maps a value to a large prime

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'd like to ask whether  there is any function that maps a value to a large prime in deterministic way, so this function always maps the same value to the same large prime.

The large prime here means given only the product of two large primes, one cannot factorize it to the original large primes.

Thanks

Comment: Well, $f(n)=P_{n+10^{1000}}$, where $P_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ prime, should suit your purposes I think

Comment: Could you be more precise about "one cannot facorize it" ? It seems like you are trying to formulate a computer science question, but even in computer science the notion of being "big enough" in order to take "too much time" to factorize is to be precisely defined...

Comment: You probably want the function to be computable and efficient? In mathematics, "functions" are not the same thing as in computer science.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime%5Bx%5D) has the function prime[n], which gives the nth prime.  Many articles use $p_n$ for the same.  If you take $n$ large, the prime is large.

Comment: As it is stated in the comment by " Thomas Andrews " I need it to be computable and efficient. Can I ask if this (or any other function) has those properties?

Comment: The usual approach would be to make a function that takes $n$ to a big number $f(n)$ of the size you want, then start testing each number above $f(n)$ until you find a prime.  Primality testing is quite quick and this is deterministic.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking questions. I am wright to say if we have an efficient function to compute large prime numbers then we could factorize the composite number that is a product of two large prime?

Comment: No.  That is the basis of the RSA  encryption algorithm. We can efficiently test a number for whether it is prime.  If I find two large primes and multiply them, the primality test will report that the product is composite. That does not help someone else find the primes.  You might read about RSA encryption-there are many references